# Run code before spring context initialization

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications, web.xml

Running a web-app over tomcat 7, my deployment descriptor contains 2 listeners, a custom one which I created and and another one of Spring:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.company.appName.web.context.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

As I'm running my integration tests, my listener is never invoked at all, so to overcome it I'm doing some initializations on my own (invoking some static method that basically are invoked from this listener on mine). Anyway, I think I'm missing something here, when does the listeners get called? Why won't the get initialized during my integration tests? To be more specific, Spring context does get initialized that's because I'm declaring it on the top of my test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:testApplicationContext.xml" })
```

So the web.xml is never actually used..

In this case, spring context always gets called first, I have no chance of doing anything before it gets initialized - Is that so? Is there a way to run some code before spring's context?

UPDATE:
I also want to mention that I'm using the @BeforeClass annotation in my test suite:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(HttpTest.class)
@SuiteClasses({ <MY TEST CLASSES> })
public class HttpSuiteITCase {

    /**
     * Run once before any of the test methods.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setTestsConfigurations() {
    TestConfiguration.setup(false);
    }
}
```

Using this approach doesn't resolve the issue, The test classes along with all my spring beans get initialized first.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate a `static` method in your test class with [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and do your initialization there.  For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:testApplicationContext.xml" })
public class TestTest {

    @BeforeClass
    static public void beforeClass() {
        // do intialization here
    }
```

If your initialization code needs access to a class field and thus can't be `static` then instead you can set up a [`TestExecutionListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html) and implement `beforeTestClass()`.   See [this blog post](http://www.tikalk.com/java/forums/how-create-after-class-methods-junit-4-using-spring-3-framework) for an example.

Comment: I did try it yesterday, and it didn't work for some reason (I tried running a @BeforeClass method from my suite so it will run only once. Today it works.. I was too sleepy yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do by using init-method in a bean, in your test context.

```
<bean id="exampleInitBean" class="examples.ExampleBean" init-method="init"/>
```

public class ExampleBean {

```
public void init() {
    // do some initialization work
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, interesting. But who can assure that this bean gets initialized first among all my spring beans?

Comment: for that you have to go through Initialization callbacks in spring and spring-bean-life-cycle. 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html.
 For assurance you could give it a try yourself.